# How to add new columns in text file with multiplication of several sequence?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I have a text file which has 4 columns with 300 lines. I want to add 5th columns where 1st hundred lines will be multiplication of 1*0.02, 2*0.02... and from hundred one lines 2.2, 2.4 ...

```
0.02 
0.04
.
.
.
2           (in 100 lines)
2.2
2.4
.
.
.
12           (in 300 lines)
```

my text file:

```
# "Frame" "Timestep" "WignerSeitz.interstitial_count" "WignerSeitz.vacancy_count"
0 0 0 0 
1 100 0 0 
2 200 0 0 
3 300 0 0 
.
.
98 9800 16 16 
99 9900 16 16 
100 10000 15 15
.
.
299 29900 48 48 
300 30000 55 55
```

expected output:

```
# "Frame" "Timestep" "WignerSeitz.interstitial_count" "WignerSeitz.vacancy_count"
0 0 0 0 0
1 100 0 0 0.02 
2 200 0 0 0.04
3 300 0 0 0.06
.
.
98 9800 16 16 1.96
99 9900 16 16 1.98
100 10000 15 15 2
.
.
299 29900 48 48 11.8 
300 30000 55 55 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supposing you mean after 100, you need to add 0.2 to each record after, Using `awk` you can do something like following code:

```
awk -v x=2 '{if($1<101){print $0 FS ($1*0.02)}else{x=x+0.2; print $0 FS x}}' file.txt
```

where:

`-v` used to let `awk` know that your are using variable `x` with initial value `2`

`$1<101` to let your first part of the code work as long as the first column is less than `101`

`FS` is static variable in `awk` that contain the field separator of your file.

Then you can adjust your step as per your requirement.

Comment: You are amazing. it is working fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want 5th column, calculated bu multiply 1st to 0.2

This can be done with `awk` for example:

```
 gawk '{printf "%s %.2f\n", $0,$1*0.02}'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a discrepancy between your spec and the sample output: from line 101 till 300 you want a step size of `0.2` but end theb last line with `12`  -  can't be. 200 steps of 0.2 will yield "40" - that will make `42` for the last line's $5 entry. Should that be true, try

```
$ awk '{print $0, ($1>100)*-18+$1*.02*(1+($1>100)*9)}' file
0 0 0 0  0
1 100 0 0  0.02
2 200 0 0  0.04
3 300 0 0  0.06
. 0
. 0
98 9800 16 16  1.96
99 9900 16 16  1.98
100 10000 15 15 2
101 10100 15 15 2.2
102 10200 15 15 2.4
. 0
199 19900 15 15 21.8
200 20000 15 15 22
201 20100 15 15 22.2
. 0
299 29900 48 48  41.8
300 30000 55 55 42
```